# npm start vs npm run start: prod

Tags: reactjs, npm

with npm start i get this page

[image]

and for npm run start : prod i get this page.
[image]

for other components it works fine for both npm start and npm run start : prod i have this bug in the prod

Answer (score 0):

**`npm start`** and **`npm run start`** are same. Both invokes the script with same parameters **`react-scripts start`**.
Please check in source code and in scripts for **production** vs **development** flags. Reference environment variable to check production or development flags `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: this is what i have in package.json "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production 
    node server",

Comment: It seems your Sidebar and other contents are rendered on some flags for this Node JS application.